# How to pass the variable value from function to calling procedure in Shellscript

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to execute few functions based on the completion of other function outputs.

Requirement:

Call func1 and func2 simultaneously 
wait until funct1 completes
once funct1 completed, call func3

Please find the same code.

---

```
l_var='N';

func1()
{
l_var='C'

# do some logic which will take time

echo "$l_var"
}


func2()
{
l_var2='C'

# do some logic which will take time

echo "$l_var2"
}

func3()
{
l_var3='C'

# do some logic which will take time

echo "$l_var3"
}

#  call function1 and function2 parallaly
func1 & func2

echo "$l_var"

# wait until funct1 complete
while [$l_var != "C"]
do

sleep 30
done

# once function1 one completed, then call function3

if [$l_var = "C"]

then
func3
fi
```

---

Issue am facing is $l_var value inside func1 printing as C but in while condition and if condition is printing as null(empty value - outside the function).

Comment: the `$l_var` you call is traditionally provided as `$LINENO` and is unique to each function call.

Comment: When you say `func1 & func2` func1 is executed in the background *in a separate shell*, so you have two variables called l_var - one in each shell. You should look at the builtin command `wait` and the variable $! to wait for func1 to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conditional commands are incorrect: the `[` is not mere syntax, it is actually a *command*. And like every command, it needs a space to separate it from its arguments.

Not

```
if [$l_var = "C"]
```

but

```
if [ "$l_var" = "C" ]
# ..^........^.^...^   mandatory whitespace
```

Note the addition of quotes around the left-hand variable. Very important.

---

The problem is that you're trying to set a global variable in a subshell. You can't do that: the child shell (created by running the function in the background) cannot alter the environment of the parent.

The most straightforward technique is to write the new value in a file and when the backgrounded process has completed (the `wait` command helps here), you can read the value from the file

```
#!/bin/bash
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
l_var='N';

func1() {
    l_var='C'
    # do some logic which will take time
    sleep 5
    echo "$l_var" > "$tmpfile"
    echo "$FUNCNAME complete"
}

func2() {
    l_var2='C'
    # do some logic which will take time
    sleep 1
    echo "$FUNCNAME: l_var2=$l_var2"
}

func3() {
    l_var3='C'
    # do some logic which will take time
    echo "$FUNCNAME: l_var3=$l_var3"
}

echo "start: l_var=$l_var"

#  call function1 and function2 parallaly
func1 &
func2

# wait for func1, then read the new value from the file
wait
l_var=$(< "$tmpfile")

echo "after func1, l_var=$l_var"

# once function1 one completed, then call function3
if [[ "$l_var" == "C" ]]; then
    func3
fi
```

outputs

```
start: l_var=N
func2: l_var2=C
func1 complete
after func1, l_var=C
func3: l_var3=C
```

Comment: After using this condition also , its not working.  Issue is l_var value is null .

Comment: It worked. In the current solution, am passing the variable value into file at the end of the each function.

Comment: Watch out when your functions end simultaneously.

Comment: If the background function returns before `wait` starts, then `wait` will return immedately.

Answer (score 0):

ksh coprocess can be handy for this

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

func1() {
  sleep $1
  echo "X${1}X"
}

func2() {
  sleep $1
  echo "Y${1}Y"
}

func3() {
  sleep $1
  echo "Z${1}Z"
}

func1 10 |&
exec 5>&p #  assign fd 5 to stdout 
exec 6<&p #  and fd 6 to stdin

func2 7 &

func3 5 |&

read -u6 F1A
read -p  F3A

echo $F1A
echo $F3A
echo "wait until all is done"
wait
```

Comment: what does this command will do read -p X?

Comment: can i read variable value for eg:

funct1()
{
sleep 5
l_var='C'
echo "X$l_varX"
}


read -p l_var

Comment: I have added one more function funct4 similar to funct1.
requirement is funct1 ,funct4 and funct2 has to submit simultaneously.

Once function 4 and funct1 completed, then funct3 has to be submitted.

Above given logic is not working for my requirement.

Getting error Process already exists.

Please help

Comment: You can only read output from coprocess.  You can end the coprocess with "echo C" and then the main process can read and get "C".  Multiple coprocesses can be started, but to communicate with them,   you will need to assign different file handles.  Please read the ksh manual about coprocesses or go to duckduckgo.com and search for examples.  In the future, try to describe your problem completely, not piecemeal.

Comment: Edited my answer, now with two coprocesses and redirected stdin and stdout, using file descriptors.

Comment: Thanks Gerard . Am trying in my environment and will keep you updated about the result. Am beginner in the shell script ,so am  asking basic questions. Please bear with me

Comment: Thanks Gerard . Am pushing the variable value to the file at the end of the each function and monitoring the file content using while loop. It worked

Comment: What a waste of energy.